# What is the most elegant way to handle non-existing attribute in python?

Tags: python, duck-typing

I'm pretty new to duck typing and have the following question.

Are there any better way then

```
try:
    what_i_want = obj.some_attr
except AttributeError: # this attribute does not exist, or something other wrong happened
    what_i_want = default_value_for_what_i_want
```

I would like to see something like a typical get value or `None` in one simple statement, something like

```
if(i is not None and i < 10):
```

Comment: Yes this is the way to do it. Though you should catch `AttributeError` rather than using a blank `except`. Blank `except` will hide other legitimate errors from you.

Comment: @Cfreak Yeah, that's correct, though I think it's not relevant to what I'm looking for. Fixing it.

Comment: You can also use [`getattr(obj, 'some_attr', default_value)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr)

Comment: @Rawing You should just post an answer.

Comment: @Rawing Are there similar solutions to member function calls?

Comment: @xxbidiao Not sure what you mean. `getattr` can also be used to get functions, you'd do something like `getattr(obj, 'function_name')(arg1, arg2)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#getattr) builtin:

```
what_i_want = getattr(obj, 'some_attr', default_value)
```

Comment: hasattr might be better for a conditional, especially if the goal is to set the value if it isn't set